# How to get CPU usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cpu

For a long time, I was thought that we can't get CPU usage from browser - because of security reason. But today, I saw that Google Meet can do that thing : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqKca.jpg

How did they do that ? Or, it's a hidden Chrome API that only works with Google's product ?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/system_cpu/

Comment: Google Meet do not require any extension

Comment: I can't read the text in that screenshot, but I'd assume they're actually deriving that information from WebRTC stats?

Comment: They actually do use a built-in extension. I don't think your website can use it.

Comment: @boygiandi It's not an extension, it's an API that's available to extensions. Google Meet likely has access to that API.